# Full height columns on Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, row-height

I'm using Foundation 5 Framework and need to create 3 same height columns.

Second columns includes 2 panels, I need to stretch all columns to full height (in the second columns there will be just second panel stretched to full height).

Any idea? I don't want to use block grid for this.

My code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <!-- here comes the content--->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <!-- here comes the content--->
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <!-- here comes the content--->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <!-- here comes the content--->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

The only solution I was able to implement uses jQuery to sync the height is from [joanhard on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/joanhard/6375966), referenced in [a Foundation 4 thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650500/zurb-foundation-4-how-to-create-a-full-height-column).

I've thrown it into codepen, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zgnBE. Here's the source in full.

### HTML

```
<div class="main">
<div class="full-height row " >
  <div class="full-height small-12 medium-4 columns " >
    <div class="full-height-panel panel "  >
      <!-- here comes the content--->
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-height small-12 medium-4 columns ">
    <div class="panel">
      <!-- here comes the content--->
      hi
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <!-- here comes the content--->
   hi2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
    <div class="panel">
      <!-- here comes the content--->
      holla
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
html, body
{
  height: 100% !important;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0;

}

.full-height
{
  display:table;
}

.full-height-panel
{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$(document).foundation();
$(".full-height").height($(".main").parent().height());
```

## Without jQuery

I tried `height:auto;` and `height:100%;` on all elements from the `panel`, `column`, `row`, `body` to the `HTML` element. The only working result produced scroll overflow due to padding or margins. I tried eliminating them but this would take longer to debug.

Comment: thank you it works! anyway, keeping foundation work also on IE8 is like nightmare.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else looking for this, this is now built in to Foundation as Equalizer
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html

From their docs:

> You can create an equal height container using a few data attributes. Apply the `data-equalizer` attribute to a parent container. Then apply the `data-equalizer-watch` attribute to each element you'd like to have an equal height. The height of `data-equalizer-watch` attribute will be equal to that of the tallest element.

```
<div class="row" data-equalizer>
  <div class="large-6 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns panel" data-equalizer-watch>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot of rendered HTML]

Answer (score 0):

In foundation (using an EM to PX conversion) their major change fire at: 640px(stack all large/medium-6). So using divs like this, the CSS with fire and make them

```
 <div class="row equalized-to">
   <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
     <div class="panel full-height">
```

Put this at the end:

```
if($(window).width()>640){ //if not stacked(no need for height)
  $(".full-height").height($(".equalized-to").height()); //find row height and apply it to all columbs by adding styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="about-us">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="columns medium-4">
    <div class="like">CONTENT 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columns medium-4">
    <div class="like">CONTENT 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="columns medium-4">
     <div class="like">CONTENT 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
<style>
.row{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
 .like{
     height:100%;
   }
</style>
```

add inner div **height="100%"**